# AngularJs Bootsrap typeahead autofill input box on hovering over the options on dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJs Bootstrap typeahead feature.

Usually when we type something that matches, the dropdown opens up. [image: Check this image]

What I want is, on hovering over the options by using the **keyboard** **keys** **up and down**, the dropdown option which has the focus should autofill the textbox.

[image]

So basically when you focus an element in your list, it needs to be put into the value field.

How can this be achieved?

This is my html

```
 <input type="text" id="myId" 
  class="form-control" ng-model="selected" 
  placeHolder="Please type here" onkeyup="scrollSubmit(event,this.value)"
  typeahead="item for item in getInput($viewValue) | limitTo:5" 
  typeahead-focus-first="false" typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item)' >
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// https://angular-ui.github.io/

// setup app and pass ui.bootstrap as dep
var myApp = angular.module("stack", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

// define factory for data source
myApp.factory("States", function() {
    var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

    return states;

});

// setup controller and pass data source
myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope, States) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;

    $scope.states = States;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stack">

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <h2><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo"> Angular.js Typeahead</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="states">Search for US States</label>
            <input name="states" id="states" type="text" placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

do you need this?@ASR

Comment: No. If I hover on Alaska,  the word Alaska gets highlighted. I want the input box to get populated with Alaska when Alaska is highlighted. Alaska should get populated into the text box when its highlighted.

Comment: But then, the filter will change, and the list will have only one item. You can change the original component, it's not so difficult, you can to create a hidden div over the input, and shows only when a item is selected, and shows the item content on this div.

Comment: or you can try others typeahead components: http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=typeahead

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I need. But I cannot use other typeahead components. I have to use bootstrap Angular UI typeahead.